# change the view size which was loaded from the xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I want to add an ad view to uicollectionview with admob native ads, and design that with `.xib` file.

[image]

And I have changed the height of the cell with

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 348);
   }
```

add the cell to collection view:

```
- (nonnull __kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifierAd" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      GADNativeAppInstallAdView *appInstallAdView =
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NativeAdInstall"
                                   owner:nil
                                 options:nil] firstObject];
    [cell addSubview: appInstallAdView];
    return cell;
}
```

but I can't change the view size and it will overlap other cells in the collection view:

[image]

Comment: are you adding ad view in collection view cell ?

Comment: yes @HiteshAgarwal

Comment: pls show your viewcontroller complete code

Comment: have put it [here](https://pastebin.com/M0HCiCr6)